# How to nest a query with Neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, subquery

I am trying to do a sort of nested Neo4j query in Java, which first labels a subset of nodes and then tries to match certain patterns among them. More specifically it is like combining 2 queries of this type:

1 - MATCH (n)-[r:RELATIONSHIP*1..3]->(m) set m:LABEL

2 - MATCH (p:LABEL)-[r2:RELATIONSHIP]->(q:OTHERLABEL) where r2.time<100 return p,r2,q

Is there a way I can merge these two query in only one using the Java function engine.execute() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'p' in query #2 will, in general, correspond to a superset of 'm' in query #1. If that is your intention, then the following should work. Notice that the 2 MATCH statements have no common variables, but a WITH is required by the Cypher syntax, so I arbitrarily picked the variable 'm' to pass to the second MATCH (even though it will be ignored).

```
MATCH (n)-[r:RELATIONSHIP*1..3]->(m)
SET m:LABEL
WITH m
MATCH (p:LABEL)-[r2:RELATIONSHIP]->(q:OTHERLABEL)
WHERE r2.time<100
RETURN p,r2,q;
```

If you intend 'm' and ''p' to be the exactly the same, then just replace '(p:LABEL)' with '(m)':

```
MATCH (n)-[r:RELATIONSHIP*1..3]->(m)
SET m:LABEL
WITH m
MATCH (m)-[r2:RELATIONSHIP]->(q:OTHERLABEL)
WHERE r2.time<100
RETURN m,r2,q;
```

Comment: Thanks! And yes I meant m and p to be exactly the same.

Comment: @cybersman in case I want to also add something like:
MATCH (p:LABEL)-[r2:RELATIONSHIP]->(q:OTHERLABEL)
WHERE r2.time<100  
AND where count(p)=3 return p;

Is it something feasible in the same query?

Comment: I know that Neo4j doesn't allow me to directly specify WHERE count(p)=3 and it requires the HAVING clause but I've been trying to do it and it seems to conflict with the WITH cause.

Comment: Try this:

MATCH (n)-[r:RELATIONSHIP*1..3]->(m)
SET m:LABEL
WITH m
MATCH (m)-[r2:RELATIONSHIP]->(q:OTHERLABEL)
WITH m, count(m) AS cm, r2, q
WHERE r2.time<100 AND cm = 3
RETURN m,r2,q;